# Resume module not working in Drupal Recruiter

Tags: 7, distributions

I'm using the **[Recruiter](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter)** distribution of drupal.

I just configured some modules, customize themes, and modules...

After an instance its resume module will not works, it shows **Access Denied** when accessing the resume pages..

I re-confirm all the permissions in the portal, But there is no change on it.

In everey instance when a confirmation message is displayed on admin panel, the following message also shown:

**resume has not been overridden because the menu item does not exist.**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3AzU.png): [image: warning message]

Help me to solve this issue...

Comment: Which theme are you using ? What module did you configure ?

Comment: Don't know more about the theme, it may be custom made... make a look at http://dreamtakeoff.com/sales/
I just configured only the default modules from drupal recruiter distribution...